# How to get multiple values from sharedPreferences on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm registering a user on my test app and save all my data to the persistent storage using sharedPreferences, but I would like to fetch those values after logging in by calling the **getData** method which has to return all data that have been saved for current registered user which will consist of his name, username, and date of birth.
So I thought of using a map since it's a dictionary kinda in java.

But I'm not sure whether I did the right thing in my catch inside the **getData**.

Bellow is my code:

```
public class AddUser {

    private static String NAME_KEY;
    private static String DOB_KEY;
    private static String USERNAME_KEY;
    private static String PASSWORD_KEY;

    Map<String,String> values = new HashMap<String,String>();

    public static void saveData(Context context, String name, String dob, String username, String password){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(NAME_KEY, name);
        editor.putString(DOB_KEY, dob);
        editor.putString(USERNAME_KEY, username);
        editor.putString(PASSWORD_KEY, password);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getData(Context context, String name, String dob, String username){
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        try{
            sharedPrefs.getString(NAME_KEY, name);
            sharedPrefs.getString(USERNAME_KEY, username);
            sharedPrefs.getString(DOB_KEY, dob);
            values = (Map<String, String>) sharedPrefs;
            return values;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return values;
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to get the returned values name, username and date of birth and display them on different fields I would like to.

Comment: I don't think you can cast a SharedPreferences to a map... I would suggest you create a User object and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Map<String, String> getData(Context context) { //other paramaters are only usefull if you want provide default values
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Map<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<String,String>(); //create the map with String->String

    String name = sharedPrefs.getString(NAME_KEY, null); //get the value
    userDetails.put(NAME_KEY, name); //put it in the map
    String username = sharedPrefs.getString(USERNAME_KEY, null);
    userDetails.put(USERNAME_KEY, username);
    String dob = sharedPrefs.getString(DOB_KEY, null);
    userDetails.put(DOB_KEY, dob);

    return userDetails; //return the map
}
```

In this case I would suggest you to use a class instead of a Map. These values are related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

`sharedPrefs.getString(NAME_KEY,name)` will return a string value which you will need to store in a variable.

SharedPreferences itself is like a hashmap, it has key value pairs, and precisely if you check in android files SharedPreferences values are stored in an xml file.

You don't need to use a map.
Just do
`String name=sharedPrefs.getString(NAME_KEY,name)`